# Why use so much of the Premium Abrasax "Regenex/Nectar"

Tags: jupiter-ascending

In Jupiter Ascending Kalique Abrasax takes a bath in what I could only identify as what is called "Premium Abrasax Regenex or Nectar", the fluid that gives these humans what seems to be eternal life.

There does not seem to be much info on the fluid at all, except that it is the most expensive and valuable resource, taking 100 humans to harvest 1 unit.

I am assuming that the fluid has limited longevity after being used, as they produce so much of it and that brings me to the question;

### Why does Kalique Abrasax takes a bath in a whole pool of it?

Do they need that much fluid for one regeneration? Or is it just a statement of how rich they are that they can use as much of it as they want?

Any in or out of universe answer is welcome.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the original film script (as written) ran to nearly 300 pages and that there was a 400 page "bible" that covered the relationships between the main characters and described the technology in depth. This was to help the makers maintain a consistent "universe" when they made the film into a long-running franchise.

Comment: One possibility: the pool is mostly water or something like DMSO, some kind of fluid to *carry* the regenix. Another possibility: the bath *is* pure regenix, but it can be used multiple times before it needs to be changed.

Comment: In two words: conspicuous consumption. If you can afford to use gallons of the most precious substance in the galaxy whenever you take a bath, you must be rich, and everyone will know it.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BloodBath

Answer (score 8):

### In-universe

**We don't know.**

There's really no indication how much Regenex is required for a single "*treatment*". The only time we see it being used is in this one sequence where the user bathes in a giant vat of the stuff. It may be that you can use smaller volumes of a lower quality for a less *aggressive* rejuvenation regime, but that isn't detailed.

Evidently this is an especially *pure* batch...

> *"There are various levels of usefulness and quality, but this is the
>   most pure and most valuable solution"*

... but quite how that purity is actually manifested (works quicker? Less painful to use? Fewer side-effects? Longer-lasting?) isn't explained in the film or any of the DVD extras.

### Out-of-universe

Although the clear implication (from a filmmaking perspective) is that you're expected to realise that this bath has cost thousands of human lives, and hence be appalled at the callousness of the "entitled" characters, the cynic in me suggests that this entire sequence was inserted into the film so that you could **see a pretty girl's bottom.**

Answer (score 0):

A very late response to your question

In the scene where Jupiter drops and breaks 1 unit of premium regenx, it has the consistency of a gel (jelly like...thin-ish jello) as it spreads across the floor

Whereas Kalique and Balem both bathe in what has the consistency of water.  We can assume since the human body is mostly water that 1 Unit added to a bath of water and the electromag tech that was used to push it into the body through the skin is what happened. 1 Unit is thinned out in the bath of pure water.  We can also assume this since it is stored and sold in single units.  If it took more than 1 unit to do the process then it would be sold in said container.  A keg, a barrel etc

We also see that Commonwealth currency is called CC (commonwealth currency) in the birbery scene, 10CC is paid by advocate Bob to the beuracratic teller...... 1 CC can  mean literally = 1 CC medical dosage since 1 liter = 1,000 CCs medical units and the containers of 1 unit pure Regenx appears to be 1 liter. So the bribe of 10CC was 10 CC of credit trade-able for 10 CCs of regenx 1/100th or 1% of a Unit.  The teller would require 100 more similar bribes to afford 1 unit....this of course does not include whatever cost required for the equipment = bathtub and tech to facilitate the process.

We can assume the medical spray used by stinger to fix Caine was an extremely watered down version.... maybe 1 CC and the rest water in the spray can

The only question is what is 1 CC value to Earth conversion currency....probably around 1 CC = $1,000 Earth currency  maybe US$ since Earth is a  tersie/ primitive planet.  1 unit of premium abrasax regenx= 1,000 CC = $1,000,000

Comment: I'm not seeing the actual answer here. Most of our answer is talking about the conversion cost or some random associations of Commonwealth currency to a unit of volume, or how to store the fluid. The question is asking *why so much Regenex was needed", if it was a show of money or that that much was required for one regeneration of life, etc.

Comment: "I'm not seeing the actual answer here." I did answer. 1 Unit is all that was necessary and the rest of the bath was WATER. compare the consistency of the broken unit = a gel to the bath = consistency water. the human body is 60% water. the bath is almost all WATER and only 1 unit of regenx is used

Comment: Why would they use Earth units of measurement?

Answer (score -1):

The broken unit is jelly like in thickness while the bath is water like consistency so obviously the bath is not 100% regenex.

Comment: This assumes that the Regenex in the containers isn't dehydrated or condensed in some fashion